How to preserve dateExpires attribute in federated Fiware Orion clusters
We are using two federated Fiware Orion clusters and encountering difficulties with the dateExpires attribute. When sending entities to the destination cluster, we noticed that the entities do not have the dateExpires attribute.
We have searched on GitHub and other documents but have not found how to configure a subscription that allows the correct transfer of this attribute between federated entities.
Additionally, we are using Orion release 4 in both clusters. We would like to confirm if the mechanism to preserve the dateExpires attribute is included in this version of Orion.
We tried the following approaches:
Subscription Configuration: Attempted various subscription configurations to include dateExpires in the notification payload, but the attribute was still missing in the destination cluster.
 curl --location 'http://ip-cluster-1:1026/v2/subscriptions' \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data '{
 "description": "Forward all entity updates to another Orion",
 "subject": {
    "entities": [
        {
            "idPattern": ".*"
        }
    ],
    "condition": {
        "attrs": []
    }
},
"notification": {
    "http": {
        "url": "http://ip-cluster-2:1026/v2/op/notify"
    },
    "attrs": [],
    "metadata": []
},
"throttling": 0
}'

Manual Attribute Addition: Manually adding the dateExpires attribute to entities in the destination cluster, which is not a feasible long-term solution.
We were expecting that the dateExpires attribute would be preserved and correctly transferred between the federated clusters based on our subscription configuration.
Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Please edit your question to include the subscription you are using (as curl command, ideally).
